# Finding the kernel of $\alpha: K[X,Y,Z]^{3}\rightarrow \langle X,Y,Z\rangle$, $(f,g,h)\mapsto Xf+Yg+Zh$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am trying to do exercise $2.3$ of Reid's "*Undergraduate Commutative Algebra*":

> Let $A=K[X,Y,Z]$ where $K$ is a field, and $m=\langle X,Y,Z\rangle$. I have to show that the kernel of the homomorphism 
>   $$
> \alpha: A^{3}\rightarrow m, (f,g,h)\mapsto Xf+Yg+Zh
> $$
>    is generated by three elements of $A^{3}$.

I think the elements are $(-y,x,0), (-z,0,x)$ and $(0,-z,y)$. It is clear that 
$\langle(-y,x,0), (-z,0,x),(0,-z,y)\rangle\subseteq\ker(\alpha)$, but I am not able to prove the other inclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know $Xf+Yg+Zh=0$. By using the long division algorithm one can write $g=Xg_1+g_2$, and $h=Xh_1+h_2$ with $g_2,h_2\in K[Y,Z]$. Plugging this into $Xf+Yg+Zh=0$ we get $Xf+XYg_1+Yg_2+XZh_1+Zh_2=0$. This shows that $Yg_2+Zh_2\in (X)$, and since $g_2,h_2$ don't contain $X$ we get $Yg_2+Zh_2=0$. Thus $Y\mid h_2$ and $Z\mid g_2$, and then $g_2=-Zu$, $h_2=Yu$, with $u\in K[Y,Z]$. Then $f+Yg_1+Zh_1=0$. Now one can write $(f,g,h)=(-Y,X,0)g_1+(-Z,0,X)h_1+(0,-Z,Y)u$.